# SerializableAttribute in dnxcore50

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, dnx

I'm trying to mark a custom exception class with [Serializable] attribute in a simple class library that is targeted both dnx451 and dnxcore50 but unfortunately I'm unable to find out in which dependency SerializableAttribute exists.

Would you please tell me how can I find dnxcore50 dependencies?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a little confusing since [SerializableAttribute is in the .NET CoreCLR repo](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/4cf8a6b082d9bb1789facd996d8265d3908757b2/src/mscorlib/src/System/SerializableAttribute.cs).  This is the source used for mscorlib.  But all the source isn't included in every variation.  Apparently it was decided to exclude binary serialization from dnxcore50 (see issues corefx [#1333](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/1333) and [#1347](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/1347) and coreclr [#1203](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/1203).

Consider using the `Newtonsoft.Json` package for serialization.